# android app crashing while clicking on Cast Mini Controller

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, chromecast

I'm developing an Android application that uses Chromecast. The video is streaming on Chromecast and Expanded controller is also working however on clicking minicontroller app crashed. Here is my log

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: class name is null
        at android.content.ComponentName.<init>(ComponentName.java:63)
        at com.google.android.gms.cast.framework.media.uicontroller.UIMediaController.onLaunchExpandedControllerClicked(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.android.gms.cast.framework.media.uicontroller.zzg.onClick(Unknown Source)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4473)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18780)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:808)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:103)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5292)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:824)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:640)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I have added following fragment definition in XML

```
<fragment
        android:id="@+id/castMiniController"
        class="com.google.android.gms.cast.framework.media.widget.MiniControllerFragment"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:visibility="gone" />
```

And here are my dependencies

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:mediarouter-v7:v7:26.2.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-cast-framework:15.0.1'
    compile 'com.googlecode.android-query:android-query:0.25.9'
}
```

Gradle version is 3.1.2. Note: I am following standard procedure, no custom codes. Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: MiniControllerFragment is the widget of Cast framework. There is no any custom code just standard procedure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That might be the case if you have not initiated NotificationOptions and CastMediaOptions inside your CastOptions class. Please add this line inside your class CastOptions :

```
NotificationOptions notificationOptions = new NotificationOptions.Builder()
        .setTargetActivityClassName(ExpandedControlsActivity.class.getName())
        .build();
CastMediaOptions mediaOptions = new CastMediaOptions.Builder()
        .setNotificationOptions(notificationOptions)
        .setExpandedControllerActivityClassName(ExpandedControlsActivity.class.getName())
        .build();
```

Please refer to the link https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/cast-videos-android/#9

Comment: I was pulling hair for 5 hours and it finally worked. Thanks